# Google Maps API - Marker Cluster Styles Prevent Image From Showing?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cluster-computing, marker

I have an issue where I am trying to change the font size and colour on the marker clusters but adding the styles prevents the image from showing? If I comment out the styles section, the image is showing correctly.

```
const cluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.map_markers, {
    imagePath: site_settings.template_directory + '/assets/images/marker-clusterer/m',
    styles:[{
        textSize: 12,
        textColor: 'white'
    }],
    maxZoom: this.map_max_zoom - 1,
    zoomOnClick: true
})
```

How can I add the styles to the marker but keep the image that is being used?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. It appears the styles object takes the image with the key **url** rather than _imagePath_. See row 56 from [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#L56). Can you move the imagePath inside styles and rename it _url_:  styles:[{url: site_settings.template_directory + '/assets/images/marker-clusterer/m', ...}],

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah this was the issue :)

Comment: Superb, I will write the answer shortly so you can tag it as answered

Answer (score 1):

As per the MarkerCluster library [GitHub](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js#L56) the style object needs an **url** which overwrites  the **imagePath**.

Solution:

```
new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.map_markers, {
    styles:[{
        url: site_settings.template_directory + '/assets/images/marker-clusterer/m1.png',
        textSize: 12,
        width: 42,
        height: 42,
        textColor: 'white'
    }],
    maxZoom: this.map_max_zoom - 1,
    zoomOnClick: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, as per Kristiyan D Kovachev's suggestion above.

```
new MarkerClusterer(this.map, this.map_markers, {
    styles:[{
        url: site_settings.template_directory + '/assets/images/marker-clusterer/m1.png',
        textSize: 12,
        width: 42,
        height: 42,
        textColor: 'white'
    }],
    maxZoom: this.map_max_zoom - 1,
    zoomOnClick: true
})
```